# MS Access 2003 Is it possible to get the following result in the report?

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access, report, iif

**In MS Access 2003 I have a report with 4 possible scenarios**

> 1.possible scenario:
>   If (Me.Ocjena1 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) And (Me.Ocjena2 = 1) And IsNull(Me.Ocjena3) Then
>   Me.Konacna_ocjena = 1
>   End If
>
> 2.possible scenario
>   If (Me.Ocjena1 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) And (Me.Ocjena2 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) And IsNull(Me.Ocjena3) Then
>   Me.Konacna_ocjena = (Me.Ocjena1+Me.Ocjena2) /2
>   End If
>
> 3.possible scenario
>   If (Me.Ocjena1 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) And l(Me.Ocjena3 =1) and (Me.Ocjena3 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) Then
>   Me.Konacna_ocjena = (me.Ocjena1+me.Ocjena3) /3
>   End If
>
> 4.possible scenario
>   If (Me.Ocjena1 = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5) And IsNull(Me.Ocjena2) And IsNull(Me.Ocjena3) Then
>   Me.Konacna_ocjena = Me.Ocjena1
>   End If

**Sometimes is included all 4 scenarios. With this code work max 2 scenarios but 2 rest not working... Where am I wrong?**

Comment: Show the rest of your code so that it's understandable what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Would have to repeat the conditional field, like:
`(Me.Ocjena1 = 2 Or Me.Ocjena1 = 3 Or Me.Ocjena1 = 4 Or Me.Ocjena1 = 5)`

Consider:

```
With Me
If .Ocjena1 > 1 And .Ocjena1 < 6 Then
    If .Ocjena2 = 1 And IsNull(.Ocjena3) Then
        .Konacna_ocjena = 1
    ElseIf .Ocjena2 > 1 And .Ocjena2 < 6 And IsNull(.Ocjena3) Then
        .Konacna_ocjena = (.Ocjena1 + .Ocjena2) / 2
    ElseIf .Ocjena2 = 1 And .Ocjena3 > 1 And .Ocjena3 < 6 Then
        .Konacna_ocjena = (.Ocjena1 + .Ocjena3) / 3
    ElseIf IsNull(.Ocjena2) And IsNull(.Ocjena3) Then
        .Konacna_ocjena = .Ocjena1
End If
End With
```